# I am creating a nodejs server with MVC parten But geting error when I am deploying it to Cpanel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes, node-modules

I am creating a nodejs server with MVC parten But geting error when I am deploying it to Cpanel
The code is below

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { connect } from './utils/dbConnect.js';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const port = process.env.PORT || 7000;
const app = express();
dotenv.config();

// mongoDB connecting using mongoose 
connect();

mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => {
    console.log("mongoDB disconnected!")
})
mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
    console.log("mongoDB connected!")
})
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("HEllo WORLD!")
})
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
    res.json([{ "name": "HASIB", }, { "name": "HASIB" }, { "name": "HASIB" }])
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    connect()
    console.log(`Connected to Backend on ${port}`)
})
```

Can you please help me to solve this issues?

I am trying to deploy nodejs app to server.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It's saying this. {We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.} but the server is running on the local server well.